# Computing Radicals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm working on the following question:

> Let $R = \mathbb{Z}_{27}$. Find $N(\langle 9\rangle)$ where $N$ is the radical of $\langle 9\rangle$.

I have so far:

$N(\langle 9\rangle) = \{x \in \mathbb{Z}_{27} | \ x^n \equiv \{0,9,18\} \mod 27\}$

Is there a quick way of checking which $x$ satisfy this? The only way I can think of is take each element of $\mathbb{Z}_{27}$ and check this condition by multiplying to itself until I see a pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always try reasoning.  What I mean is that in this case, it’s obvious $3^2\in (9)$, so $(3)$ is contained in the radical of $(9)$, and $(3)$ is a maximal ideal in $\mathbb Z_{27}$, so it is exactly the radical of $(9)$.

It should also be said that the *nilradical* refers to the radical of the zero ideal. Usually you call what you’re describing “the radical” of the ideal. Of course, that radical of $I$ corresponds to the nilradical of the quotient ring  $R/I$.

Comment: why does it follow form $3^2 \in \langle9\rangle$ that the entire ideal $\langle 3 \rangle \subset N(\langle9\rangle)$?

Comment: @yoshi By definition, it means $3$ is in the radical of $(9)$, and therefore the entire ideal generated by $3$ is in $(9)$.